# Compilar assembly preparado para Linux no OSX

Tags: compilação, assembly, osx, x64, projeto-de-compiladores

Estou tentando fazer um estudo de compiladores, para tal tenho de compilar um assembly de uma linguagem chamada howto com nasm.

o código intermediário gerado pelo compilador do howto é o seguinte:

```
extern printf
segment .text
align 8
global main:function
main:
segment .rodata
align 8
_L1: db 'hello', 10, 0
segment .text
    mov rax, 0
    mov edi, $_L1
    call printf
    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

no terminal do OSX faço `$ nasm -f macho out.asm`, e tenho erro de compilação por causa do `main:function`, se remover o `:function` termina com este primeiro erro ao se tentar compilar novamente. Mais um erro, mas desta vez ele apenas diz que devo utilizar `macho64` por causa da arquitetura do sistema, tento compilar com `$ nasm -f macho64 out.asm` e tenho o erro:

> out.asm:11: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses

Depois disto não consigo mais compilar, porem se utilizo ELF64 consigo criar o arquivo `out.o`.

Deste ponto com o arquivo `out.o` a qual devo compilar com o clang, faço `$clang out.o -v` para retornar toda a verbose e recebo o erro:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o a.out out.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
  ld: warning: ignoring file out.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): out.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Deste ponto não consigo avançar mais, tentei fazer o link por ld com `$ ld -e _main out.o` e `$ ld -e _main out.o -arch x86_64` porem nestes casos recebo a mensagem de erro:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

No linux a compilação com `$ nasm -f elf64 out.asm` foi sem problemas do jeito inicial do código e o `$ gcc out.o` também gerando o arquivo a.out que ao executar retornava a resposta `Hello` da mensagem esperada. Porem como tenho de terminar este projeto no OSX peço ajuda a comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho a certeza do que estou a dizer!!! mas aqui vai de qq modo:

A arquitetura dos intel 80-86 e descendentes é uma trapalhada!

(ao contrário do linux) no OSX o espaço de endereçamento excede 2^32 portanto não costuma suportar endereçamento absoluto com 32 bits.

**update**: Portanto: usar registos de 64bits ou endeçamente relativo:

#### Registos de 64 bits:

```
global main
extern puts

segment .text
main:
    push rbp      ; (guardar o frame pointer -- *1)

    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, _L1  ; usando o registo de 64 bits corresp ao edi
    call puts

    pop rbp       ; (retaurar o frame pointer -- *1)
    mov rax, 0    ; (return 0 do C)
    ret

_L1: 
   db "hello",  0
```

notas:

- as linhas `*1`não são necessárioas para este caso mas
  são uma boa prática...
- usei `puts` em vez do `printf` para ficar mais simples

alternativamente -- usar **endereços relativos** (sem boas práticas...):

```
global main
extern puts

segment .text
main:
    mov eax, 0          ; registo de 32 bits correspondente ao rax
    lea edi, [rel _L1]  ; registo de 32 bits...             ao rdi
    call puts
    ret

_L1:
   db "hello",  0
```

**Untested** ...eu esperaria que estas versões funcionassem tanto em macho64 (OSX) como em elf64 (linux).
PF. diz-me se funciona: -- não tenho máquinas de 64bits para testar

Comment: Nada certo, gera o erro `out.asm:12: error: invalid operand size specification`. Neste caso adicionei ao inicio do documento `default rel` e como pedido coloquei no lugar de `move edi, $_L1` o rel para ficar `move edi, rel $_L1`.

Comment: @ThiagoPrado -- rescrevi a minha tentativa de solução. Podes verifivar de funciona e se faz sentido?

Comment: Então @JJoao, desculpe a demora para verificar, porem não tive sucesso, no caso de seu primeiro exemplo ao compilar tenho o retorno da mensagem: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
  "puts", referenced from:
      main in alt02.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.
O segundo exemplo também tive um erro parecido. Todos os exemplos tentei compilar com `nasm -f macho file.asm` e `nasm -f macho64 file.asm`.

Comment: @ThiagoPrado, vamos ver passo a passo: 1) `nasm -v` (para verificarmos a versão) 2) `nasm -f macho64 file.asm` (deu erros?) 3) `cc  file.o` (deu erros) 4) .`/a.out`

Comment: Vamos la então. 1) NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Mar 10 2015, logo ultima versão do repositórios do brew. 2) Aqui ok, cria o arquivo .o sem problemas e erros e sem mensagens. 3) `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
  "puts", referenced from:
      main in alt02.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Este é o erro ao compilar com cc.

Comment: Para ajudar a versão do meu clang `Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix`.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme este post no SO em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091987/x64-nasm-pushing-memory-addresses-onto-the-stack-call-function

O endereço da mensagem `'hello'` deve, obrigatoriamente, ser relativo.

E, conforme este post aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696320/trouble-linking-printf-and-scanf-in-assembly-x86-64-and-c-file-on-mac-osx

As funções são prefixadas por um underline `'_'`.

Portanto, a função `main` deve ser alterada para `_main` (ponto de entrada do programa), assim como a `printf`, alterada para `_printf`.

O registrador `rbp` deve ser salvo para evitar um erro de segmentação.

Abaixo, segue o programa já com as alterações:

```
        extern _printf
        global _main

_main:

segment .rodata

        align 8

_L1:    db 'hello', 10, 0

segment .text

        push rbp          

        mov rax, 0
        lea rdi, [rel _L1]
        call _printf
        mov rax, 0

        pop rbp
        ret
```

Para compilar:

```
nasm -f macho64 out.asm
```

Para linkar:

```
clang out.o
```

Abaixo, o output de execução:

```
$ ./a.out
hello
$
```

Compilado com `NASM version 2.11.08` em um sistema  `OS X El Capitan`.